# Using React's shouldComponentUpdate with Immutable.js cursors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I'm having trouble figuring out how to short circuit rendering a branch
of a tree of React components using Immutable.js cursors.

Take the following example:

```
import React from 'react';
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import Cursor from 'immutable/contrib/cursor';

let data = Immutable.fromJS({
  things: [
    {title: '', key: 1},
    {title: '', key: 2}
  ]
});

class Thing extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.thing.deref() !== nextProps.thing.deref();
  }

  handleChangeTitle(e) {
    this.props.thing.set('title', e.target.value);
  }    

  render() {
    return <div>
      <input value={this.props.thing.get('title')} 
        onChange={this.handleChangeTitle.bind(this)} />
    </div>;
  }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const cursor = Cursor.from(this.props.data, 'things', newThings => {
      data.set('things', newThings);
      renderContainer();
    });

    const things = cursor.map(thing => (
      <Thing thing={thing} key={thing.get('key')} />
    ));

    return <div>
      {things}
    </div>;
  }
}

const renderContainer = () => {
  React.render(<Container data={data} />, document.getElementById('someDiv'));
};
```

Say I change the first `Thing`'s title. Only the first `Thing` will render with
the new title and the second `Thing` will not re-render due to
`shouldComponentUpdate`. However, if I change the second `Thing`'s title, the
  first `Thing`'s title will go back to `''` since the second `Thing`'s cursor
is still pointing at an older version of the root data.

We update the cursors on each render of `Container` but the ones that don't
render due to `shouldComponentUpdate` also don't get the new cursor with the updated
root data. The only way I can see keeping the cursors up to date is to remove
`shouldComponentUpdate` in the `Thing` component in this example.

Is there a way to change this example to use `shouldComponentUpdate` using fast referential
equality checks but also keep the cursors updated?

Or, if that's not possible, could you provide an overview of how you would generally work with cursors + React components and rendering only components with updated data?

Comment: Does adding a 'key' to the Thing help? It's required for lists of things to work correctly.

Comment: The thing must hold onto its own state, and the owner component should hold onto whether it exists in that list. You're changing props, which is a big no-no.

Comment: I've written a boilerplate, which includes the example above, using Omniscient. Available here: https://github.com/datashaman/react-quickie

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add a `key` prop to each `Thing` component -- I've updated the example. However that won't solve this issue as it's the `thing` prop that gets changed because the cursor changes on each update.

Omnicient seems to accomplish something similar using cursors and Immutable.js but I couldn't quite understand the implementation on the admittedly short time I've spent with it. I was hoping if there was no direct solution to the question someone could provide a high level explanation of how a tool like Omniscient accomplishes what we're trying to do here.

Comment: The omniscient documentation is a little fragmented, but this guide here is good at explaining what's going on in omniscient. Not sure if it warrants an answer for you, but it comes close. http://omniscientjs.github.io/guides/01-simpler-ui-reasoning-with-unidirectional/

Comment: Have you ever tried https://github.com/arqex/freezer instead of Immutable & cursors? Much more lightweight and easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code, see comments inline:

```
class Thing extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.thing.deref() !== nextProps.thing.deref();
  }

  handleChangeTitle(e) {
    // trigger method on Container to handle update
    this.props.onTitleChange(this.props.thing.get('key'), e.target.value);
  }    

  render() {
    return <div>
      <input value={this.props.thing.get('title')} 
        onChange={this.handleChangeTitle.bind(this)} />
    </div>;
  }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.initCursor();
  }

  initCursor() {
    // store cursor as instance variable to get access from methods
    this.cursor = Cursor.from(data, 'things', newThings => {
      data = data.set('things', newThings);
      // trigger re-render
      this.forceUpdate();
    });
  }

  render() {
    const things = this.cursor.map(thing => (
      <Thing thing={thing} key={thing.get('key')} onTitleChange={this.onTitleChange.bind(this)} />
    ));

    return <div>
      {things}
    </div>;
  }

  onTitleChange(key, title){
    // update cursor to store changed things
    this.cursor = this.cursor.update(x => {
      // update single thing
      var thing = x.get(key - 1).set('title', title);
      // return updated things
      return x.set(key - 1,thing);
    });
  }
}

const renderContainer = () => {
  React.render(<Container data={data} />, document.getElementById('someDiv'));
};
```